Is there anyway to download a google dataform repository?
Created a google bigquery dataform repository with few development workspaces in it. Is there a way to download the entire repo?

I'm also curious to understand the thinking behind the question.  If you could download the repo files to your workstation ... what would you do with that data?

You can just connect it to a Git repository. Go to "Settings" in your workspace and connect them to a repository and respective branch. Then if you still want to download everything, you should be able to do it from there.
Here is the oficial Google documentation on how to do it https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/connect-repository

I think this is the right answer ... to add ... there are also APIs available.  It appears that two may be useful .... projects.locations.repositories.queryDirectoryContents and projects.locations.repositories.readFile both seem applicable. see ... https://cloud.google.com/dataform/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.repositories
